# Working with Charindex and right function when the value is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Basically I am trying to get a file name from a column that captures the whole path.  Below   select statement actually worked before the database got refreshed.  Now it is failing because there are no files uploaded recently.

Here is the error I am getting: 
Error: Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.

```
SELECT right(batch_ID, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(batch_ID)) - 1) AS [File Name]
from
table1
```

Please help me figure out how to change the statement so if there is a null value or if charindex cannot find '\' it would still work.

Thanks!

Comment: Prepend backslash to batch_id before you reverse it: `SELECT right(batch_ID, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE('\' + batch_ID)) - 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a case statement, something like:

```
declare @path as varchar(100);
set @path = '';

select case when CHARINDEX('\', coalesce(@path, ''),1) > 0 
            then right(@path, CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(@path)) - 1) 
            else null end
```